# Named Credential for WebSocket

Tags: lightning-web-components, namedcredentials, websockets

I have a requirement to make POST callouts to an endpoint allocated inside a WebSocket and I want when trying to configure the `Named Credential` it gives me the following error:

`Endpoint needs to be in full URL form`

Is this even possible?

And if not, how can I configure this to be working and being able to make POST requests to the WebSocket authorizing first?

Regards,

Comment: You can't use WebSocket technology with Named Credentials. Named Credentials only work with HTTP(S) 1.x technology. It can't do other protocols like HTTPS2 or FTP, for example. Instead, if you're intending to call these services from the client, you'll have to handle authentication on the client.

Comment: WS is only available in the front-end, isn't it?

Comment: when I tried WebSockets 2 years ago it wasn't supported by LWC, needed to use Visualforce page to connect and pass token from Protected Custom Metadata. Might be new security model supports them